# Symfony 2 - Checking Action Permission with Roles and Groups

Tags: symfony, permissions, fosuserbundle, roles

I'm new into Symfony 2 and I read some docs about ACL and the ROLE System. 
I understood that I can use different Permissions on a Object with ACL.

But I need some different ( ? ) type of permission check, like in the static apache turbine roles / permission sets.

I want to use FOSUserBundle and using Groups. 
The Groups should have permissions like 
DOWNLOAD_PDF
DOWNLOAD_PPT
INVITE_USERS
and so on..

Stuff that does not have something to do with Objects but I have to check in Controller ( static ) and assign to Groups in an Userinterface.

I don't really found something about how to check those Permissions and assign them e.g. to Groups.

Is there something already exist? Or a best practice?
Or should I create for every Permission I need a ROLE?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think it's the proper way to go to create for every permission a role and assign those roles to your groups (many to many relation). Your user would then be assigned to one group.